# bootstrap glyphicon wrong position when col-md is used

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I will illustrate the question with some images.

So this is what i got:

[image]

But when i add `col-md-6` then it gets a bit weird:

[image]

As you can see the glyphicon is not inside the input anymore. I could create a class in css like this:

```
.glyphicon-md {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

But why does this happen ? And is it possible to fix this without the use of css.

```
<!-- LastName -->
<div class="form-group col-md-6"  ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$invalid, 'has-success has-feedback': form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$valid  }">
    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.client.lastName" required />

    <div  class="help-block"  ng-messages="form_addClient.lastName.$error" ng-if="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty">
        <div ng-message="required">The client needs a last name.</div>
    </div>

    <span ng-show="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
    <span ng-show="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove  form-control-feedback"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try to wrap your `form-group` div with another `col-md-6` not in the same `div` ... check the differences in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju7u53u7/2/)

like below

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group"  ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback': form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$invalid, 'has-success has-feedback': form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$valid  }">
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.client.lastName" required />

        <div  class="help-block"  ng-messages="form_addClient.lastName.$error" ng-if="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty">
        <div ng-message="required">The client needs a last name.</div>
        </div>

        <span ng-show="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
        <span ng-show="form_addClient.lastName.$dirty && form_addClient.lastName.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove  form-control-feedback"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```